# Using sed to replace string matching regex with wildcards

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string I'm trying manipulate with sed

```
js/plex.js?hash=f1c2b98&version=2.4.23"
```

Desired output is

```
js/plex.js"
```

This is what I'm currently trying

```
sed -i s'/js\/plex.js[\?.\+\"]/js\/plex.js"/'
```

But it is only matching the first ? and returns this output

```
js/plex.js"hash=f1c2b98&version=2.4.23"
```

I can't see why this isn't working after a few hours

Comment: Try [`echo 'js/plex.js?hash=f1c2b98&version=2.4.23\"' | sed s/[?][^\"]*//g`](http://ideone.com/DF7RN2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
echo 'js/plex.js?hash=f1c2b98&version=2.4.23"' | sed  s:.js?.*:.js:g
```

With the original Regex:

Firstly I would suggest use a different delimiter (like `:` in sed when using / in the regex. Secondly, the use of `[]` means that you are matching the **characters** inside the brackets (and as such it will not expand the `.+` to the end of the line - you could potentially try put the `+` after the `[]`)

Comment: good explanation as to the brackets but be careful as to the ".* " since this can match greedily if placed at begining  of pattern

Comment: Your tip about using the greedy match outside of the brackets solved it for me, will mark as answer later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
sed 's#\(js/plex.js?\)[^"]\+".*#\1#g'
```

..

```
\# is used as a delimiter
```

`\(js/plex.js?\)[^"]\+".*`  #find this pattern and replace everything with your marked pattern `\1` found

**The marked pattern**

In sed you can mark part of a pattern or the whole pattern buy using `\( \)`. .

When part of a pattern is enclosed by brackets `()` escaped by backslashes..the pattern is marked/stored...

in my example this is my pattern **without marking**

```
js/plex.js?[^"]\+".*
```

but I only want sed to remember `js/plex.js?` and replace the whole line with only this piece of pattern `js/plex.js?` ..with sed the first marked pattern is known as `\1`, the second `\2` and so forth

```
\(js/plex.js?\) ---> is marked as \1
```

Hence I replace the whole line with `\1`

Comment: See Ismail M answer what the brackets are actually doing  in sed

Comment: Could you elaborate on the marked pattern bit with an example?